# vb.net open "random access" files

Tags: vb.net, file

I want to open any post in a DAT file. The file has rows of fixed length strings containing name, email etc. I tried binaryreader like this:

```
Private Sub btnOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim fil As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    Dim reader As BinaryReader
    reader = New BinaryReader(File.Open(fil, FileMode.Open))

    txtName.Text = reader.ReadString(30)
    txtKlasse.Text = reader.ReadString(5)
    txtEpost.Text = reader.ReadString(25)
```

I can do it with Fileopen, but understand this is a dated solution? I'm learning vb.net and want to learn the most modern way.

Comment: Is it a binary file or plain text?  Does each row contain a name, e-mail, etc. or are they each on a separate line?

Comment: Personally, I'd use `File.ReadAllLines`. Then I'd write a helper function `String[] SplitStringByIndices(int[])` which splits the values with `Substring`. Then, I'd access the values in the resulting array by their position.

Comment: Taegost: It is a binary file I think, .DAT. Each row has one post regarding one person (this is a non-mandatory school assignment I'm trying to understand)

Comment: Heinzi: thanks for your solution, but I am want to learn how to use binaryreader or equivalent.

Comment: I agree with @Heinzi, he's correct. The current way/ route you are going in inefficient and error prone. You are contradicting yourself as well, `but I am want to learn how to use binaryreader or equivalent` doesn't make sense with `I'm learning vb.net and want to learn the most modern way`... If you do I would take his advice; he's not in the **top 0.15%** of all users for nothing :)

Comment: I will take your advice, I'd be stupid not to. Can I limit File.ReadAllLines to one line at a time(one "post")?

Comment: @SveinArne: You can use `For Each line in File.ReadAllLines(...)`, if that's what you mean. In that case, you can also use the (defered) `File.ReadLines`.